# Error: The Mongo server and the Meteor query disagree on how many documents match your query. Maybe it is hitting a Mongo edge case? The query is: {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

```
Exception in defer callback: Error: The Mongo server and the Meteor query disagree on how many documents match your query. Maybe it is hitting a Mongo edge case? The query is: {}
I20180319-12:18:14.344(5.5)?     at packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:881:15
I20180319-12:18:14.345(5.5)?     at Object.Meteor._noYieldsAllowed (packages/meteor.js:730:12)
I20180319-12:18:14.345(5.5)?     at OplogObserveDriver._publishNewResults (packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:851:12)
I20180319-12:18:14.345(5.5)?     at OplogObserveDriver._runQuery (packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:758:10)
I20180319-12:18:14.346(5.5)?     at OplogObserveDriver._runInitialQuery (packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:658:10)
I20180319-12:18:14.346(5.5)?     at packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:191:10
I20180319-12:18:14.346(5.5)?     at packages/mongo/oplog_observe_driver.js:15:9
I20180319-12:18:14.346(5.5)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1186:26)
I20180319-12:18:14.347(5.5)?     at packages/meteor.js:502:25
I20180319-12:18:14.347(5.5)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1238:24)
```

This is the full exception I'm getting, it started coming as I update meteor to 1.6.1 from 1.6.0, on change in code just updated my meteor, I can't show the code as it's confidential but can some give me any hint on what part of my code should I look for example : on helpers, meteor call, meteor method, router etc.

Or can any body give me idea why this error came.

Comment: You could rewrite the code using common variable names and defy your confidential information. Providing a code example is crucial in order to help people with these kinds of problem.

Comment: I actually don't have a sample code i have whole website of more than 90 files I don't know which part of code I have to alter that's why I asking on what should I look on to solve the problem for example : on helpers, meteor call, meteor method, router etc.!

Answer (score 3):

In case you haven't found a solution yet:

This bug comes from the handling of `undefined` values in Mongo and JSON/EJSON.

Because undefined doesn't exist in JSON, the key-value pair gets stripped from the query before being passed to Mongo. This is why the error says `The query is: {}`.

Meteor have a fix for this in the pipeline for the next version, but in the mean time you can update affected queries to test for undefined and replace it with `null`

---

reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9619

Comment: In case it helps anyone else I have also seen this when queries with undefined key/value pairs like this are used in `$or` statements:  `{"$or":[{"key":"value"},{},{},{},{},{}]}`